# how to pass AWS lambda 1 output as lambda 2's input using BOTO 3

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I have a AWS lambda function which have some info and another 6 lambda functions which query cloudwatch logs using BOTO 3.

How can i call lambda 2 with lambda 1 input.

I'm calling 6 other lambdas because execution time taking more than 48 mins to query logs. I've divided time duration into 6 parts and calling each lambda with some start and end times, As lambda execution time is 15 mins max

lambda 1 code

```
import json
import boto3
import time

client = boto3.client('lambda')

payload3=b"""{ "query":"fields @timestamp, @message | sort @timestamp desc", "log_group":"abc.log", "sTime":1585630748456, "eTime":1585713248457}"""

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='testamurin',
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=payload3
    )

   return {
        'statusCode': 200
    }
```

lambda 2

```
import json
import boto3
import time

client = boto3.client('logs')

def lambda_handler(event,context):

    response = client.start_query(
        logGroupName = log_group,
        startTime=sTime,
        endTime=eTime,
        queryString = query
    )

    query_id = response['queryId']

    response = None

    while response == None or response['status'] == 'Running':
        print('Waiting for query to complete ...')
        time.sleep(1)
        response = client.get_query_results(
            queryId=query_id)

    return {
        'body': response
    }
```

When i'm running lambda1 its getting successful. But, in lambda 2 i'm getting error

```
[ERROR] NameError: name 'log_group' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in lambda_handler
    logGroupName = log_group,
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the code you are use to invoke the lambda function and any error messages you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "call lambda 2 with lambda 1 input"? What is invoking the 2nd Lambda function? Why are you using two separate Lambda functions? Please edit your question to provide more information about the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the function 1 is calling function 2

Function 1 input contains `first_name` and `last_name`

## Function 1

```py
import json
from boto3 import client as boto3_client

lambda_client = boto3_client('lambda')

def my_handler(event, context):
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="FUNCTION-2-NAME-FOUND-IN-LAMBDA-CONSOLE",
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(event)
    )
    # do something with the response
    # ...
```

## Function 2

```py
def my_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'], 
                                    event['last_name'])  
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```